# Why constuct Instance<Integer> instead of int

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am following [this](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/master/guide/NumberguessQuickstart.asciidoc) WildFly Java EE tutorial.

I have a question about the following code:

```
@Inject
@MaxNumber
private int maxNumber;

@Inject
@Random
Instance<Integer> randomNumber;
```

Why is in the `maxNumber` case an `int` injected and in the `randomNumber` case an `Instance<Integer>`?

I have tested the code using `int randomNumber` and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Instance javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html):

> In certain situations, injection is not the most convenient way to
>   obtain a contextual reference. For example, it may not be used when:
>
> - the bean type or qualifiers vary dynamically at runtime, or
> - depending upon the deployment, there may be no bean which satisfies the type and
>     qualifiers, or
> - we would like to iterate over all beans of a certain type.

So if bean is marked as `@Random` then value is deploy-time depended and should be wrapped by `Instance`. `Instance` is generic so it needs Object type `Integer` not primitive `int`.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with the value is deploy-time depended? I read the javadoc, but that part I do not understand.

Comment: It was imprecise. If object (type) came from package that is not CDI (does not contains `bean.xml`) then I won't trigger bean discovery process. So you need `Producer` that create object (condition 2 - cannot determine bean at start). In addition because it is vary  at runtime (it's random) then it need to be `Instance`.